# How to create a prepared SELECT statement in SQLite on Android platform

Tags: java, android, sqlite, prepared-statement

I'm working on Android platform with Java and SQLite. I know SQL and jdbc fundamentals and i want, for performance reasons, to use a prepared statement to extract data from DB. For INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations i have already used SQLiteStatement.

Is there a way to use prepared statement for SELECT operation with standard SQLite interface offered by Android SDK?

Comment: I'm curious to know why this question receive -1. It not an useless or stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) and [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) always create a temporary statement.
[SQLiteStatement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) works only for queries that return a single value.

The Android database API does not have any mechanism to create a prepared statement for a query.

(Compiling a statement is extremely fast in SQLite, but that cannot be the reason because prepared statements are supported for other statement types.)